# Querying total sum of a column in PHP from Oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

this question is kinda newbie but I am in the process of learning database.

So I am querying the total of a column and I want to show it in PHP

```
$sumSql = "select sum(weight) as total_sum from master_drawing";

$sumParse = oci_parse($conn, $sumSql);

oci_bind_by_name($sumParse, "total_sum", $total);

oci_execute($sumParse);

while(oci_fetch($sumParse)){
    echo $total;
}
```

But somehow, the error is like this:

Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\newEmptyPHP.php on line 30

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sumSql = "select sum(weight) as total_sum from master_drawing";

$sumParse = oci_parse($conn, $sumSql);

oci_define_by_name($sumParse, "TOTAL_SUM", $total);

oci_execute($sumParse);

while(oci_fetch($sumParse)){
    echo $total;
}
```

You have to use, `oci_define_by_name`, and column names always by CAPS.